# dynamic json array object

Tags: jquery, json

I fetching data from database using json in jQuery and asp.net and I am doing this for each table each time. Is there any way to create one function and pass some parameters like (Columns name, Table name and control to show in) for all tables.

```
function LoadData(Url, Data, ControlToShow, Columns){
    $.ajax({ type: "post",
        url: Url,
        data: Data,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d != null || data.d != 'null') {
                var items = data.d;

                $("#" + ControlToShow).append(items[0].Columns[1]);
            }
        }
}
```

Or in another words to use json array object dynamic by passing the column name like

```
var items = response.d;
var colName = 'Customers';
alert(items[0].colName);

colName = 'CustomerID';
alert(items[0].colName);
```

Or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this :-

```
function LoadData(Url, Data, ControlToShow, ColumnName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: Url,
        data: Data,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d != null) {
                var items = data.d;
                $("#" + ControlToShow).append(items[0][ColumnName]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and call it like:

```
LoadData(serviceUrl, {data_you_need_to_pass}, 'ControlID', 'CustomerID');
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can access the properties just by accessing them by name:

```
var items = response.d;
alert(items[0].Customers);  
alert(items[0].CustomerID);
```

or if the name of the properties is stored in a variable, you can access them like:

```
var items = response.d;
var colName = 'Customers';
alert(items[0][colName]);

colName = 'CustomerID';
alert(items[0][colName]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create your json something like this. so you can read column and data to create table.

```
     {"column_name":['column1','column2','column3'],"records":[{'id':1 ...}]}
```

CHECK THE EDIT CODE,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ABZC9/1/)

```
        $(function(){
            var json ={"column_name":['ID','COUNTRY'],"records":[{"id":1 ,"name": "USA"},{"id":2 ,"name": "INDIA"},{"id":3 ,"name": "AUSTRALIA"}]};
            var column_arr = json.column_name;
            var column_arr_length = column_arr.length;//no of column present.

            // creating table header
            var $thead = $('#mytable thead');
            var row = '<tr>'
            for(var i= 0; i< column_arr_length;i++){
                row += '<th>'+column_arr[i]+'</th>';
            }
            row += '</tr>';

            $thead.append(row);// adding head to table

            // creating table body
            var $body = $('#mytable tbody');
            var body_data = json.records;
            var body_data_length = body_data.length;//no of row in  body.
            var body_row = '';
            for(var i= 0; i< body_data_length;i++){
                var row_obj = body_data[i];
                console.log(row_obj);
                body_row += '<tr>';
                for(var key in row_obj){
                    body_row += '<td>'+row_obj[key]+'</td>';
                }
                body_row += '</tr>';
            }

            $body.append(body_row);// adding rows to table
        })
```

HTML CODE

```
    <table id="mytable">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: can you provide me with an example of asp.net and json

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template view and pass in the data for each table. In the body section you can could simply iterate over the data and append it to the body section of your table.

```
<table id="<%= YOUR TABLE NAME %>">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><% YOUR COLUMN NAME %></th>
....
</tr>
<thead>
<tbody class="mytable"></tbody>
...
</table>

success: function (data) {
            if (data.d != null || data.d != 'null') {
                var items = data.d;

var tr = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo('.mytable');
                $.each(data.d, function(){

                  //append your td elements to your tr above

                });
            }
    }
```